# Unable to get typeahead suggestions using Angular

Tags: angular

Tried below code for getting typeahead suggestions, query is triggered and response coming but autosuggestions are not populating. if we enter again the data autosuggestions are coming and observed `this.testData.filter` is not a function in console.

```
testData: any = [];
  model: any;
  fnPopulateDataLovs(){
    this.http
      .get("/api/sampleAPI", {
        params: {
          name: (document.getElementById('typeahead-format') as HTMLInputElement).value
        },
      })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.testData = res;
      });
  }

  search: OperatorFunction<string, readonly string[]> = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : this.testData.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
  
  ngOnInit() {

  }
```

Html:

```
<input id="typeahead-format"
 type="text" 
 class="form-control" 
 [(ngModel)]="model" 
 [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
 (keyup)="fnPopulateDataLovs()"
 />
```

Comment: Be careful about `this` context. You are giving it as a callback, so you may have surprises.

Comment: The context of `this` won't change in arrow functions @Random

Comment: @SagarV That's the theory, indeed, but I have the same kind of code on one of my apps, where `search` is an arrow function, but still see `cannot access xxx of undefined` (because of `this` context) triggered in prod. It works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't, and was not able to find when/why...

Comment: @Random that might be something else. You can figure out it easily. I've never faced such problems in last 4 years.

Comment: @SagarV I agree, I'm also really surprised to see these in prod logs, but the code is really simple, I access `this.foo` inside the `search` arrow function, and the error says `cannot access foo of undefined`. There is no way `this` should be undefined when declaring it in an arrow function. So I guess it comes from Angular messing things up while giving the function to the child, or when the component is being destroying, or idk... I changed the arrow function to a method, and doing `this.search = this.search.bind(this)`, and it seems to works better...